# PHP Create Timeslots with break hours

Tags: php

I made this Code to make time slots:

```
$duration = 60;
$cleanup = 0;
$start = "10:00";
$end = '24:00';

function timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end)
{
  $start = new DateTime($start);
  $end = new DateTime($end);
  $interval = new DateInterval('PT' . $duration . 'M');
  $cleanupinterval = new DateInterval('PT' . $cleanup . 'M');
  $slots = array();

  for ($intStart = $start; $intStart < $end; $intStart->add($interval)->add($cleanupinterval)) {
    $endperiod = clone $intStart;
    $endperiod->add($interval);
    if ($endperiod > $end) {
      break;
    }
    $slots[] = $intStart->format('H:iA') . '-' . $endperiod->format('H:iA');
  }

  return $slots;
}
?>
```

above code get results like this:

1. 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM.
2. 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM.

what I'm trying to do is something like this:

1. 12:00 AM - 01:00 AM
2. 01:00 AM - 02:00 AM

**3. 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM**

4. 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM.

So I'm trying to make break time from **02:00 AM to 10:00 AM**

so the day will start like:

**12:00 AM** To **02:00 AM** and take **breake hours from 02:00 AM** To **10:00 AM**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...and your question / problem is? Did you try anything yet? What problem did you encounter? This isn't a free write-my-code service, and "I want" isn't a question. You need to show some attempt to research and/or implement something to try and solve your requirement. And then we can _help_ you with it if you find a problem. We won't just do it all for you, unless it's very trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already made a lot of attempts and failed, so I asked if someone could show me the Idea of it and or how to make it.
Thanks again.

Comment: Paraphrase your question please. Your current question is not clear what is meant by this.

Comment: Please show your best attempt then, and explain what went wrong. Maybe it's nearly right and  we can fix it for you. Better than starting again.

Comment: I paraphrased my question.

Comment: please explain in terms of your input/output, I couldn't figure out how those inputs will generate your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this will help You:

```
    $duration = 60;
    $cleanup = 0;
    $start = "00:00";
    $end = '24:00';
    $break_start = '02:00'; // break start
    $break_end   = '10:00'; // break end
    
    function timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end, $break_start, $break_end)
    {
      $start = new DateTime($start);
      $end = new DateTime($end);
      $break_start  = new DateTime($break_start);
      $break_end    = new DateTime($break_end);
      $interval = new DateInterval('PT' . $duration . 'M');
      $cleanupinterval = new DateInterval('PT' . $cleanup . 'M');
      $slots = array();
    
      for ($intStart = $start; $intStart < $end; $intStart->add($interval)->add($cleanupinterval)) {
        $endperiod = clone $intStart;
        $endperiod->add($interval);
        if (strtotime($break_start->format('H:i A')) < strtotime($endperiod->format('H:i A')) && strtotime($endperiod->format('H:i A')) < strtotime($break_end->format('H:i A'))) {
          $endperiod = $break_start;
          $slots[] = $intStart->format('H:i A') . ' - ' . $endperiod->format('H:i A');
          $intStart = $break_end;
          $endperiod = $break_end;
          $intStart->sub($interval);
        }
        $slots[] = $intStart->format('H:iA') . '-' . $endperiod->format('H:iA');
      }
    
      return $slots;
    }

and 

$time_slots = timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end, $break_start, $break_end);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($time_slots);
echo '<pre>';
```

the result will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00:00 AM - 01:00 AM
    [1] => 01:00 AM - 02:00 AM
    [2] => 02:00 AM - 02:00 AM
    [3] => 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM
    [4] => 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM
    [5] => 12:00 PM - 13:00 PM
    [6] => 13:00 PM - 14:00 PM
    [7] => 14:00 PM - 15:00 PM
    [8] => 15:00 PM - 16:00 PM
    [9] => 16:00 PM - 17:00 PM
    [10] => 17:00 PM - 18:00 PM
    [11] => 18:00 PM - 19:00 PM
    [12] => 19:00 PM - 20:00 PM
    [13] => 20:00 PM - 21:00 PM
    [14] => 21:00 PM - 22:00 PM
    [15] => 22:00 PM - 23:00 PM
    [16] => 23:00 PM - 00:00 AM
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
function show_time_slots($start_time, $end_time, $duration, $break){

  $time_slots = array();
  $start_time = strtotime($start_time);
  $end_time = strtotime($end_time);

  $add_mins  = $duration * 60;

  while ($start_time <= $end_time)
  {
    $time_slots[] = date("H:i", $start_time);
    $start_time += $add_mins;
  }

  $time_slots = array_diff( $time_slots, $break );

  return $time_slots;

}
```

And

```
$start_time = '00:00';
$end_time = '23:00';
$duration = '60';
$break = ['03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00'];

$time_slots = show_time_slots($start_time, $end_time, $duration, $break);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($time_slots);
echo '</pre>';
```

Return

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00:00
    [1] => 01:00
    [2] => 02:00
    [10] => 10:00
    [11] => 11:00
    [12] => 12:00
    [13] => 13:00
    [14] => 14:00
    [15] => 15:00
    [16] => 16:00
    [17] => 17:00
    [18] => 18:00
    [19] => 19:00
    [20] => 20:00
    [21] => 21:00
    [22] => 22:00
    [23] => 23:00
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make a function that will help you to make all possible slots. the function will take the start_time and end_time and based on the duration(in minutes) it will make the slots and it will not create a slot during break time also you can add clean-up or refresh time after every slot if you want that argument will take time in minutes.

I also see that the approved answer of @Khaled Mostafa where copied by a lot of bloggers and they just copy and paste his answer in the same requirement as mine but it didn't help me in this kind of my requirement so after spending some hours I have found this solution.

```
function show_time_slots($start_time, $end_time, $duration, $break_start, $break_end, $cleanup = 0){

    $time_slots = array();
    $start_time = strtotime($start_time);
    $end_time = strtotime($end_time);

    $break_start = strtotime($break_start);
    $break_end = strtotime($break_end);

    $add_mins  = ($duration + $cleanup) * 60;

    while ($start_time <= $end_time)
    {
      $startSlotTime = date("h:i A", $start_time); // for 24 format date("H:i", $start_time);
      $slotEndTime = $start_time + $add_mins;
      $endSlotTime = date("h:i A", $slotEndTime); // for 24 format date("H:i", $slotEndTime);

      // $sachin = strtotime($startSlotTime);
      if($slotEndTime <= $end_time){
        if(
          ($start_time > $break_start  &&  $start_time < $break_end ) || ($slotEndTime > $break_start && $slotEndTime < $break_end )
          || ($break_start > $start_time  &&  $break_start < $slotEndTime) || ($break_end > $start_time  &&  $break_end < $slotEndTime)
          ){
        
          $start_time = $break_end;
        }else{
          $time_slots[] = $startSlotTime . "-" . $endSlotTime;
          $start_time += $add_mins;
        }
      }else{
        $start_time += $add_mins;
      }
    }

    // $time_slots = array_diff( $time_slots, $break );

    return $time_slots;

}

$duration = 180; // minutes
$cleanup = 0; // minutes
$start_time = "10:00";
$end_time = '23:00';
$break_start = '16:00'; // break start
$break_end   = '16:30'; // break end

$time_slots = show_time_slots($start_time, $end_time, $duration, $break_start, $break_end, $cleanup);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($time_slots);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Out Put**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10:00 AM-01:00 PM
    [1] => 01:00 PM-04:00 PM
    [2] => 04:30 PM-07:30 PM
    [3] => 07:30 PM-10:30 PM
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am getting solution for multiple break too. pleas check my answer and tell me if anything wrong with this. no doubt I am using code of @Sachin Sarola I just changes few line as I required for multiple break slot.

```
function show_time_slots($start_time, $end_time, $duration, $break_arr, $cleanup = 0){

$time_slots = array();
$start_time = strtotime($start_time);
$end_time = strtotime($end_time);

$add_mins  = ($duration + $cleanup) * 60;

while ($start_time <= $end_time)
{
  $startSlotTime = date("h:i A", $start_time); // for 24 format date("H:i", $start_time);
  $slotEndTime = $start_time + $add_mins;
  $endSlotTime = date("h:i A", $slotEndTime); // for 24 format date("H:i", $slotEndTime);

  if($slotEndTime <= $end_time){

    $is_break = false;
    $last_break_end_time = null;
    foreach($break_arr as $key => $break){
      $break_start = strtotime($break['break_start']);
      $break_end = strtotime($break['break_end']);
        if(
          ($start_time > $break_start  &&  $start_time < $break_end ) || ($slotEndTime > $break_start && $slotEndTime < $break_end )
          || ($break_start > $start_time  &&  $break_start < $slotEndTime) || ($break_end > $start_time  &&  $break_end < $slotEndTime)
          ){
          $is_break = true;
          $last_break_end_time = $break_end;
          break;
      }
    }


    if($is_break && $last_break_end_time){
      $start_time = $last_break_end_time;
    }else{
      $time_slots[] = $startSlotTime . "-" . $endSlotTime;
      $start_time += $add_mins;
    }
  }else{
    $start_time += $add_mins;
  }
}

// $time_slots = array_diff( $time_slots, $break );

return $time_slots;

}

$duration = 180;
$cleanup = 0;
$start_time = "10:00";
$end_time = '23:00';
$break_start = '16:00'; // break start
$break_end   = '16:30'; // break end

$break_arr = [
  ['break_start' => '16:00', 'break_end'  => '16:30'],
  ['break_start' => '19:30', 'break_end'  => '20:00']
];

$time_slots = show_time_slots($start_time, $end_time, $duration, $break_arr, $cleanup);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($time_slots);
echo '</pre>';
```

Out Put

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10:00 AM-01:00 PM
    [1] => 01:00 PM-04:00 PM
    [2] => 04:30 PM-07:30 PM
    [3] => 08:00 PM-11:00 PM
)
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a me too question ?